# Remove a single line from a text file using php

Tags: php

I have a text file like
somerandomtext

abc morerandomtext def

evenmorerandomtext

What I want to do, is replace "morerandomtext" with "otherrandomtext", right now I have a function that finds the line with morerandomtext and explodes it at morerandomtext. It works fine, except that the replaced text is ADDED to the text file, instead of replacing the "morerandomtext".

Here's my function

```
function c_replaceInFile($path,$target,$replacement){
    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path)){
        $handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path, 'r+');
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $readLine = $line;
            if(c_findAfter($target,$readLine,true) != ""){
                $temp = explode($target,$readLine,2);
                $out = $temp[0].$replacement.$temp[1];
                //remove $line here

                fputs($handle,$out);
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }else{
        getError("Error: file $path doesn't exist","otherErrors");
    }
}
```

**I don't want to load the file into a single array, since the files will be huge,** unless it won't slow down/crash the server with 100mb text files.

tl;dr:
I need a function that will remove $line.

I assume php doesn't have the function I'm looking for. Nevermind about this question, I'll just try to use mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a new file.
Write the non-edited files to it. The edited also.
At the end overwrite the previous file with the new one.

Use file_put_contents() to overwrite.

Comment: As I said, the files will be huge. Copying one would take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.xxx');

$content = str_replace($target, $replacement, $content);

file_put_contents('file.xxx', $content);
```

Comment: It does the same as my function - adds a new line instead of replacing it.

Comment: @user3569990 That's because your reading and writing in the same file so the new lines gets amended. Try saving the file with a different name and then overwrite the existing one. Or see updated answer.

Comment: @user3569990 Above should even work with large files.

Answer (score 0):

if they change once a day just run a cron job in the middle of the night.

I think john's answer could work well enough.

otherwise try using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) It finds the occurence string you could use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to do something with the given result.

```
$a = 'abc morerandomtext def';
if (strpos($a,'morerandomtext ') !== false) {
    ***doyourthing***
}
```